# How to access isolated scope variables from angular components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, isolate-scope

Considering this situation, where i am relying on fileupload component which is been used in 3 places in the same form distinguished with value binded.

A Total of 3 components in use distinguished with one variable binded

In that particular isolated controller. There are value being set.

How can i fetch those values independently w.r.to that particular scope?

**Example:**

```
<test-component type="abc"></test-component>
```

Component consists of one input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.input" />
```

Inside controller

```
  vm.type = this.type // abc

  vm.input from 1st component will be suppose: 'foo'
  vm.input from 2nd component will be suppose: 'boo'
  vm.input from 3rd component will be suppose: 'goo'
```

Now the requirement is need to form validate if all `vm.input` is entered. So, how can i fetch those individually and test it?

constraint is `vm.input` already has function binding. Could not change its names

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Comment: As an example i constructed this small typical example. But, actual code is w.r.to upload of files and that's a huge effort for me to create a plnkr at present. Still, will try to update it given sometime. Much appreciated if this can be solved without even plnkr.

Comment: What binding is used for the `test-component` attribute named `type`? Attribute `@` binding, one-way `<` binding, or expression `&` binding? For more infomation, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Comment: It is @ binding